# Incorporate custom bootstrap build into project grunt task

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, less, gruntjs, bower

I have a project structure like this...

```
app
├── 404.html
├── coffee
│   ├── app.coffee
│   └── controllers
├── colors.json
├── components
│   ├── angular
│   ├── angular-cookies
│   ├── angular-mocks
│   ├── angular-resource
│   ├── angular-sanitize
│   ├── angular-scenario
│   ├── bootstrap
│   ├── es5-shim
│   ├── jquery
│   └── json3
├── favicon.ico
├── index.jade
├── lib
│   ├── bootstrap
│   ├── font-awesome
│   ├── jquery
│   └── slider
├── robots.txt
├── styl
│   ├── main.styl
│   └── partials
└── views
    ├── demo.jade
    └── home.jade
```

And I am using bower to install all the things in the `app/component` folder. I am planning to add a custom variables file to bootstrap and build it from the less source. I can easily modify the `variables.less` file after `bower install` creates the `app/bootstrap` folder, but I want it to read my custom file from outside the `components` folder, and not to have to modify anything within.

How could I incorporate the building of bootstrap, using custom `variables.less` file, loaded by bower into my existing `grunt build` task?

Answer (score 3):

It took me a while to work out how less's variable declarations and importing work, but in the end, I have a custom build of bootstrap by importing it through less, and compiling less via grunt - so my solution has nothing to do with grunt really, but kicks in as part of the grunt build.

Contents of my project's `main.less` file...

```
// import the default bootstrap variables...
@import "../components/bootstrap/less/variables.less";

// custom variable overrides have to be loaded BEFORE bootstrap.less
// this is useful for changing any variables that influence the way bootstrap is built
@import "_bootstrap-variables-overrides.less";

// load the main bootstrap file
@import "../components/bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less";

// components overrides have to be loaded AFTER bootstrap.less
// this is useful for overriding bootstrap styles that are not configurable as variables
@import "_bootstrap-components-overrides.less";

// more less...
/* ... */
```

Answer (score 2):

The proper 'yeoman' way to do this seems to be the [grunt-customize-bootstrap](https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-customize-bootstrap) npm package.

Just install it and add a grunt task in your grunt compile process as explained on the package page, and it should be ok !

Comment: Thanks for this link, looks interesting. I ended up getting it to work by importing into less files using less's own `@import`. See my answer...